# Rails 5: record_tag_helper continues to give an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my project with `content_tag_for` I had an error:

> The `content_tag_for` method has been removed from Rails. To continue
>   using it, add the `record_tag_helper` gem to your Gemfile:   gem
>   'record_tag_helper', '~> 1.0'

So, I added [this gem](https://github.com/rails/record_tag_helper) to my Gemfile. `$ bundle install` returns:

> Using record_tag_helper 1.0.0

I have restarted server, cleared Rails cache and so on, but I still have the same error, that content_tag_for method has been removed from Rails. I just have no more ideas why it doesn't work.

Share your ideas, please.

Comment: @widjajayd I already read it and added gem 'record_tag_helper', as you can see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added "require 'record_tag_helper'" to my `application.rb` file and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Github page, the gem has not been updated in 2 years. Also the last update contains the message 'Prep for Rails 5'. I'm assuming that this gem isn't compatible with Rails 5.

Comment: But as I understood it was made for Rails 5 :)